# How to preload programs?

Tags: boot, cache

What I want to do is open some programs in the boot sequence so Ubuntu loads them into memory. I'm already using the preload package and it's not helping in that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It should be possible to force `ureadahead` to load the programs during boot. Do achieve this:

1. Delete the .pack files in `/var/lib/ureadahead/`:
   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `gnome-terminal` → `sudo rm /var/lib/ureadahead/*.pack`
2. Make sure you are using automatic login:
   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `gdmsetup`
3. Reboot.
4. Once your desktop loaded, quickly start the programs you want to preload during boot.
5. To check if it worked, you can check, if the files are listed in the newly generated .pack files, e.g.:
   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `gnome-terminal` → `ureadahead --dump | grep "gedit"`
6. If a program is not included, you can extend the phase during which ureadahead waits after boot, by editing the file `/etc/init/ureadahead.conf`:
   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `gnome-terminal` → `gksu gedit /etc/init/ureadahead.conf`

   Then increase the sleep time in the last line: `pre-stop exec sleep 45` and go back to 1.

Comment: If I wanted to allways include certain file in the pack, how do I not lose them on reproilfe? See my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/71395/possible-to-use-ureadahead-to-cache-frequently-used-programs